# Illegal import declaration with gulp-react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to introduce React with ES6 into my app, which is built with Gulp.  I can get React working alone, and ES6 working alone.  But trying to `import` crashes my Gulp build.  Gulp's error is:

> Line 14: Illegal import declaration

My HTML page includes React and the built JS file:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

`app.js` looks like this:

```
import {Child} from './child.js';

var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    const y = 3;  //es6 works
    return (
      <div>
        <div> This is the parent {y}. </div>
        <Child name="child"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

`child.js` is in the same directory and looks like this:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        and this is the <b>{this.props.name}</b>.
      </div>
    )
  }
});

export default Child;
```

The part of my Gulp file that compiles ES6 with Babel:

```
gulp.task('babel', function(){
  gulp.src('js/app.js')
    .pipe(react())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

What am I missing/doing wrong that is preventing me from using `import`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply the `es6module` option to `gulp-react` to allow for importing of modules:

```
.pipe(react({
  es6module: true
}))
```

Then, fix your import statement. Since `Child` is exported as default, import it like this:

```
import Child from './child.js';
```

---

Note: `gulp-react` was deprecated in favor of `gulp-babel` so I suggest using that instead if you're already using it for `es2015`. use `gulp-babel` instead and install the `react` preset for Babel:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

Finally, apply it to `gulp-babel`:

```
presets: ['es2015', 'react']
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I think that worked, but after doing this I got another error. 
 In the browser I was getting a console error from require `Module name xxx has not been loaded yet for context`.  So I've dropped Babel and am using Webpack to compile the React code and looks good now.

Comment: @AlanP. Oh, yes. Babel isn't actually a module loader itself, it's just a transpiler thus the error occurs. Using Webpack also transforms the modules for the web and is way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
import Child from './child';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Badacadabra  I don't mind the points and reputation. I provided the working code and the user above answered it with explanation, so there is no point on giving the same explanation as Andrew's one. **If he didn't** provided the answer with explanation, I would have add the explanation.